# JDBC exception on Hibernate data access

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jdbc

On local machine all works fine. But when I tried to do get request on server machine, hibernate throws the following exception:

> JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [n/a];
>   SQL state [HY000]; error code [1030]; could not extract ResultSet;
>   nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException:
>   could not extract ResultSet

what can be the reason for this?

Comment: Please provide a FULL stacktrace, as this is not very helpful for others... As indicated in the answer of @Marco Tulio Avila Cerón

Answer (score 0):

You don't give so much information, only some ideas I could think of:

- Locally mysql runs in Windows and remotely in Linux or vice versa?, check for the case sensitive on both DB's.
- User configuration for permission on tables on the remote server.
- Check the filesystem in the remote machine?, enough space in hard disk?, see:
  http://codetheory.in/fixing-mysql-error-1030-hy000-got-error-28-from-storage-engine/

Comment: I used default settings on mysql. I tried make get request on windows && linux local machines. All right. I have not permission to server machine, and i dont can see server logs. I think too, that problem is in hibernate or mysql configurations on server